# Grouped listview crashes on second refresh

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I've got a grouped Xamarin ListView, and found it troublesome updating the values within the ListView.

ViewModel;

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<ObservableGroupCollection<string, TaskItem>> _userTasksGrouped;
    public ObservableCollection<ObservableGroupCollection<string, TaskItem>> UserTasksGrouped
    {
        get => _userTasksGrouped;
        set
        {
            _userTasksGrouped = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void PopulateMyTasks()
    {
        UserTasks.Clear();
        foreach (var task in MyTasks)
        {
            UserTasks.Add(new TaskItem(task));
        }
        DoTaskGrouping();
    }

    private void DoTaskGrouping()
    {
        UserTasksGrouped.Clear();
        var groupedData =
            UserTasks
                .OrderBy(ut => ut.Name)
                .GroupBy(ut => ut.StateEnum.ToString())
                .Select(ut => new ObservableGroupCollection<string, TaskItem>(ut))
                .ToList();
        foreach (var group in groupedData)
            UserTasksGrouped.Add(group);
    }

    public void UpdateTaskItem(TaskChanged taskChanged)
    {
        // update listing
        var usertask = UserTasksGrouped.First(utg => utg.Any(ut => ut.Task.Id == taskChanged.Task.Id))
            .First(t => t.Task.Id == taskChanged.Task.Id);
        if (usertask != null)
        {
            usertask.Task = taskChanged.Task;
        }
        else
        {
            // something else
        }
        DoTaskGrouping();
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        UserTasks = new ObservableCollection<TaskItem>();
        UserTasksGrouped = new ObservableCollection<ObservableGroupCollection<string, TaskItem>>();
    }
}
```

XAML;

```
<ListView 
    IsGroupingEnabled="true"
    ItemsSource="{Binding UserTasksGrouped}"
    GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"
    GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding Key}">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <BoxView
                            Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            MinimumHeightRequest="16"
                            MinimumWidthRequest="16"
                            Margin="0"
                            Color="{Binding StatusColour}" />

                        <Label
                            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                            Text="{Binding Name}"
                            Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"
                            WidthRequest="200" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Task Item:

```
public class TaskItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MyTask _task;
    public MyTask Task
    {
        get => _task;
        set
        {
            _task = value;
            Name = value.Name;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string StatusColour => "Green"
}
```

The problem when I call DoTaskGrouping() for the second time to force a refresh the App crashes with an UnhandledException. I managed to track this down to a "An item with the same key has already been added" error, so I added the ViewCell.View thinking it might fix things. Please help, I have a few questions;

1. How do I fix the error "An item with same key has already been added" and successfully refresh my grouped listing.
2. Do Observable collections within observable collections update themselves. Meaning if the properties or what their grouped by changes, so does the grouping? Meaning an item can move between groups?
3. Is my approach sound from a MVVM perspective? TaskItem could do with cleaning up.

Comment: See link may be it's help you
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/34229/an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added-exception-when-adding-nested-scrollview-to-xaml

Comment: Thanks, I've read that and previously added a ViewCell.View. Sadly it doesn't help my situation, still crashes on refresh.

Comment: where is _userTasksGrouped created?

Comment: try to create your observable collection each time in the "DoTaskGrouping" method instead of clear/add

Comment: @hugo Thanks! This works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by removing from the MainViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<ObservableGroupCollection<string, TaskItem>> UserTasksGrouped
```

DoTaskGrouping() building the collection afresh each time;

```
UserTasksGrouped = new ObservableCollection<ObservableGroupCollection<string, TaskItem>>(groupedData);
```